# generalisation between vector and matrix, matrix and tensor with numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I found an interesting thing when comparing MATLAB and numpy.

```
MATLAB:
x = [1, 2]
n = size(X, 2) 
% n = 1

Python:
x = np.array([1, 2])
n = x.shape[1]
# error
```

The question is: how to handle input which may be both ndarray with shape (n,) and ndarray with shape (n, m).

e.g.

```
def my_summation(X):
    """
    X : ndarray
        each column of X is an observation.
    """
    # my solution for ndarray shape (n,)
    # if X.ndim == 1:
    #     X = X.reshape((-1, 1))

    num_of_sample = X.shape[1]
    sum = np.zeros(X.shape[0])
    for i in range(num_of_sample):
        sum = sum + X[:, i]

    return sum


a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([1, 2])

print my_summation(a)
print my_summation(b)
```

My solution is forcing ndarray shape (n,) to be shape (n, 1).

The summation is used as an example. What I want is to find an elegant way to handle the possibility of matrix with only one observation(vector) and matrix with more than one observation using ndarray.

Does anyone have better solutions?

Comment: What is wrong with reshaping?

Comment: For a 1D case, since you are summing along `axis=1` and you wanted `(n)` to become `(n,1)`, so for a 1D array case the output from `my_summation(X)` would be same as input `X`, right?

Comment: @mose there is nothing wrong with reshaping. I just want to find an elegant way to handle the possibility of matrix with only one observation and matrix with more than one observation using ndarray.

Comment: @Divakar in 1D case, the summation is still X with shape (n,). By the way, what is the pros and cons of returning sum as (n,) versus (n,1)?

Comment: @user2262504 I don't see any con in that, just a different shape occupying the same number of elements.

Comment: @Divakar For me, I would always worry about situations, where ndarray with shape(n,) + a ndarray with shape (n,1). the result is much different than  ndarray with shape (n,) + ndarray with shape (n,)

Comment: @user2262504 In MATLAB, you have the luxury that you can work along any dimension, whereas in NumPy, you would need to explicity assign the dimensions with reshaping or other techniques. So, yeah you need to take care of shapes within the function definitions.

Comment: Alternatively, you could *require* the argument to be 2-d, and raise an error if the input is 1-d. From the Zen of Python: *In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.*  The ambiguity here is the meaning of an an array with shape (n,).

Comment: A fundamental difference is that Matlab matrices are always 2d or larger.  In early versions they were always 2d, like `np.matrix`.

Comment: Imagine in MATLAB that you working with matricies that are nomally 3d (tensors), but certain operations might reduce them to 2d?  Isn't that the same issue as this 2d v 1d in numpy?

Answer (score 1):

In a ndarray `X`, `len(X)` would the number of elements along the first axis. So, for a 2D array, it would be the number of rows and for a 1D array, it would be the number of elements in itself. This property could be used to reshape the input array that could be a 1D or a 2D array into a 2D array output. For a 1D array as input, the output 2D array would have number of rows same as number of elements. For a 2D array input case, it would have the number of rows same as before, therefore no change with it.

To sum up, one solution would be to put a reshaping code at the top of the function definition, like so -

```
X = X.reshape(len(X),-1)
```

Sample runs -

2D Case:

```
In [50]: X
Out[50]: 
array([[6, 7, 8, 1],
       [6, 2, 3, 0],
       [5, 1, 8, 6]])

In [51]: X.reshape(len(X),-1)
Out[51]: 
array([[6, 7, 8, 1],
       [6, 2, 3, 0],
       [5, 1, 8, 6]])
```

1D Case:

```
In [53]: X
Out[53]: array([2, 5, 2])

In [54]: X.reshape(len(X),-1)
Out[54]: 
array([[2],
       [5],
       [2]])
```

Comment: By saying "put at the top of the function definition" `X = X.reshape(len(X),-1)` , do you mean to use the reshaping before passing the input, or reshaping the input in the function itself? Thank you for your solution.  My solution is similar to yours : `# my solution for ndarray shape (n,)
    # if X.ndim == 1:
    #     X = X.reshape((-1, 1))`

Comment: @user2262504 I meant right after `def my_summation(X):`, the first line of the function could be the reshaping.

Answer (score 1):

I recently learned about `numpy.atleast_2d` from the Python control
toolbox.  You also don't need a for-loop for summation, rather use
`numpy.sum`.

```
import numpy as np


def my_summation(X):
    """
    X : ndarray
        each column of X is an observation.
    """
    # my solution for ndarray shape (n,)
    # if X.ndim == 1:
    #     X = X.reshape((-1, 1))
    X = np.atleast_2d(X)
    return np.sum(X, axis=1)


a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([1, 2])

print my_summation(a)
print my_summation(b)
```

gives

```
[3 7]
[3]
```

Comment: use summation is just a example to show off my situation. I know np.sum

Comment: `np.atleast_2d` reshapes `(n,)` to a shape `(1, n)` instead of `(n,1)`, right?

Comment: Yes, it appears to treat a 1-d array as a row-vector.  It has the virtues of not changing 3-or-higher-dimensional arrays, and also handles 0-dim "arrays".  Your solution, which treats 1-d arrays as columns, obviously always turns 3-d and higher into 2-d, (which might be OK depending on application) but doesn't handle 0-d.  You could use `len(a.flatten())` to handle 0-d as well.

Comment: MATLAB freely adds dimensions on the right `(n,1,1,1,...)`; `numpy` can do the same (during broadcasting), but on the left `(...1,1,n)`.  Keep that difference in mind when translating code.